# Como fazer com que uma entrada errada do usuário não dê bug no programa?

Tags: c

Exemplo, eu declarei a opção do menu como `int`, daí o bichinho de orelha vai lá e digita uma letra ou um caractere especial e isso vai fazer o programa bugar. A pergunta é: tem como resolver isso?

Exemplo:

```
int opc;
printf("Digite uma opção");
scanf("%d", &opc);
```

Quando o cara digitar letra, número quebrado ou caractere especial vai bugar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Verifica o valor devolvido pelo `scanf()`:

```
if (scanf("%d", &opc) != 1) /* erro */
```

Melhor ainda é usar `fgets()` seguido de `sscanf()`:

```
char tmp[20];
if (!fgets(tmp, sizeof tmp, stdin)) /* erro */;
if (sscanf(tmp, "%d", &opc) != 1) /* erro */;
```

---

*Edit*

Neste último código introduzi a variável `tmp` para ter um local temporário onde guardar o input do utilizador em caracteres até o transformar em número.

O `fgets()` lê esses caracteres do utilizador e mete-os em `tmp`. O valor devolvido por `fgets()` é o endereço de `tmp`, excepto em caso de erro quando `fgets()` devolve `NULL`. É isto que o `if` verifica, se houve erro durante o processamento de `fgets()`.

```
if (!fgets(...)) /* ... */;
// estas duas pseudo instruções são iguais
if (fgets(...) == NULL) /* ... */;
```

O `sscanf()` funciona como o `scanf()`. A diferença está no input. O `scanf()` recebe input do `stdin` (do teclado); o `sscanf()` recebe input duma string (a string que o utilizador escreveu e que está guardada em `tmp`).
Em qualquer dos casos o valor que o `scanf()` (ou `sscanf()`) devolve é o valor de atribuições efectuadas, ou `EOF` em caso de erro.
No nosso caso temos apenas 1 atribuição possível, portanto temos apenas 3 valores de retorno possíveis para o `sscanf()`. Ou devolve `1` que quer dizer que a instrução correu bem a ele atribuiu o valor à variável `opc`; ou devolve `0` que quer dizer que não conseguiu atribuir valor (por exemploo utilizador escreveu "vinte"); ou ainda devovle `EOF` para indicar erro interno da função.
Ou seja qualquer coisa excepto `1` não nos interessa.

```
int chk = sscanf(tmp, "%d", &opc);
if (chk == EOF)  /* erro interno */;
if (chk == 0) /* input com erro */;
if (chk == 1) /* tudo ok */;
```

Comment: Não entendi muito, no caso eu teria de criar uma condição para se for diferente de 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 e assim por diante?

Comment: Não, basta criar uma condição caso `scanf("%d", &opc) == 1` faça oq você quer. Duas podem ser criadas com o caso `else` para fazer algo caso a leitura não seja um int (no seu caso). **Essa comparação com o scanf não é com o valor do item lido, é com o número de itens lidos com sucesso.**

Comment: Entendi.. Eu apliquei no meu software, daí ele até funciona, quando eu entro com um valor não inteiro ele vai pra tela de erro, mas dai que tá, ele não saí dela, nem mesmo com um goto pedindo pra voltar pra tela do menu

Comment: Nao sai do erro porque o scanf continua a achar o valor errado no buffer. Quando introduzes, por exemplo, "X<ENTER>" para a opcao, o scanf ve o 'X' e indica que nap consegue converter o input num numero. Como o mandas converter outra vez, e ele acha o mesmo 'X' outra vez volta a dar erro ... e volta a tentar e dar erro ... ... ... Se usares `fgets()` seguide `sscanf()`, como o `fgets()` remove tanto o 'X' como o '<ENTER>' do buffer o problema resolve-se automaticamente.

Comment: Tem que incluir alguma biblioteca? Aqui deu erro de sintaxe do sscanf e ! do fgets

Comment: Tanto `sscanf()` como `fgets()` fazem parte da biblioteca padrao do C; nao precisas de fazer nada de especial a este respeito. Os prototipos estao em `<stdio.h>`; certifica-te que tens este header incluido. O erro de sintaxe pode ser duma instrucao anterior ...

Comment: Funcionou, era outra coisa errada aqui.. Só não entendi muio bem o código.. Se (não for lido numero inteiro) e Se(for lido um inteiro que tenha um caracter) seria isso? o que é o vetor tmp? Só pra entender mesmo

Comment: @LeonardoVIlarinho adicionei uns comentários a minha resposta. Se precisares de mais informações, posta as tuas dúvidas.

Comment: Muito bom, consegui entender, obrigado aí