# PROBLEMA COM FGETS no C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*definir operador lógico para chuva (1 para TRUE e 0 para FALSE) */

#define TRUE (1==1)
#define FALSE (!TRUE)

struct eventos_atm_st {
float temp;
float press;
int chuva;
int mm_prec;
char nome[200];
};

typedef struct eventos_atm_st eventos;

void ler_estrutura(eventos *dados){
printf("Qual temperatura?\n");
scanf("%f", &dados->temp);
printf("Qual pressao?\n");
scanf("%f", &dados->press);
printf("choveu?\n");
scanf("%d", &dados->chuva); /*definir 1 para true e 0 para false */
printf("Qual mm_prec?\n");
scanf("%d", &dados->mm_prec);
printf("Qual nome?");
fgets(dados->nome,200,stdin); /*problema, está ficando algum "lixo de memória" que não deixa meu fgets capturar o nome*/



}



int main(){

eventos node[3];
int i;

for(i=0;i<3;i++){
ler_estrutura(&node[i]);
}


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Primeiro, [não misture `fgets` com `scanf`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/87974/132). Depois, [veja aqui como resolver isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/69093/132).

Comment: Ah, e só para esclarecer. Não fui eu quem negativou você. Pelo contrário, considero a sua dúvida válida.

Answer (score 0):

## Como Resolver

Esse problema é causado pelo próprio funcionamento de `scanf`. Para resolvê-lo, basta modificar este trecho de código:

```
scanf("%d", &dados->mm_prec);
printf("Qual nome?");
fgets(dados->nome,200,stdin); /*problema, está ficando algum "lixo de memória" que não deixa meu fgets capturar o nome*/
```

para:

```
scanf("%d", &dados->mm_prec);
fflush(stdin);
printf("Qual nome?");
fgets(dados->nome,200,stdin); /*problema, está ficando algum "lixo de memória" que não deixa meu fgets capturar o nome*/
```

A função `fflush` serve para limpar um *fluxo de dados*, no caso o fluxo `stdin`, que é o fluxo do qual você quer ler os dados necessários para o funcionamento do programa. Ao usar `fflush` antes de `fgets`, você estará limpando o lixo criado por `scanf`.

## O que ocasiona o problema?

O problema está na própria função `scanf`. Analise, por exemplo, a seguinte chamada para a função scanf:

`scanf("%d", &variavel);`

Faz **exatamente** o que você pediu: Ela lê **inteiros**: Números que você digitar em stdin. Por isso, quando você digita:

`450`

E aperta enter, qual foi a string criada nesse processo? Oras, se `scanf` só lê os números que foram digitados pelo usuário, ela obtem os seguintes caracteres de stdin:

`4`, `5` e `0`

Mas ela **ignora** o seguinte caractere, que não é um número:

`\n`

É isso mesmo! Quando você aperta a tecla **enter** para que scanf realize sua leitura, scanf ignora o enter inserido em stdin. Portanto, o stdin passa de:

`450\n`

Para:

`\n`

Assim, quando `fgets` for ler a string que o usuário supostamente deveria ter digitado, ele já encontra o caractere de nova linha `\n` em `stdin`, que foi deixado para trás por `scanf`. Desta forma, `fgets` é basicamente "ignorado" pelo seu código. É por isso que você deve usar `fflush` após scanf: Para limpar esses resquícios deixados por `scanf`.

Comment: Muito obrigado!!!

Comment: Fico contente por ter ajudado! Se tiver dúvidas, é só perguntar