# fgets dando erro no laço for

Tags: c, string

Gostaria de saber o porque o fgets está pulando uma linha sempre que entra no laço for.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char nome[5][10];

int i, tam;

int main(){
    printf("\nTamanho: ");
    scanf("%d",&tam);

    for (i=0; i<tam; i++){
        printf("\nEntrada: ");
        fgets(nome[i], 10, stdin);
        
    }

    for (i=0; i<tam;i++){
        printf(nome[i]);
    }
}
```

[image: O resultado no terminal aqui:]

Defini q iam ser 3 entradas. Ele começa pulando a primeira, permite a entrada na segunda e pula a terceira.

Comment: A primeira é pulada por causa [disso](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5240789). Dê uma olhada [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/69094/112052) para uma alternativa de solução.

Comment: Obrigado por tentar me ajudar, mas não tinha conseguido entender praticamente nada da solução proposta. Por sorte encontrei algo mais fácil para o meu problema em questão, apesar deu não saber se é algo 'certo' ou viável. O importante é q para minha tarefa funcionou. Obrigado de novo.

Comment: Basicamente, os links que indiquei explicam que misturar `scanf` com `fgets`/`getchar`/etc não é uma boa, porque `scanf` nem sempre consome a quebra de linha (o "ENTER"), e `fgets`/`getchar` acaba lendo essa quebra de linha e "pulando" a leitura. Por isso, uma solução é ler sempre com `fgets` e se for o caso, converter para número (ou para o que vc precisar) com `sscanf` (repare que tem um "s" a mais no início). Assim: https://ideone.com/NwMwT9

Comment: Lembrando que em código mais "sério" vc tem que verificar cada função deu certo, além de outros detalhes (`fgets` inclui a quebra de linha na string, mas se vc digitar mais caracteres que o tamanho indicado - que no caso é 10 - eles serão lidos na próxima chamada, então vc precisa limpar o buffer, etc). Enfim, em C vc tem que fazer tudo na mão conforme a necessidade e não tem um único jeito certo. Ex: https://ideone.com/4RFgyc (repare que ele só lê os primeiros caracteres - veja a diferença quando não limpa o buffer: https://ideone.com/iRHImo)

Comment: Vou dar uma lida em tudo que me passou. Vai ser bom pra que eu aperfeiçoe mais meus conhecimentos. A faculdade não tá ensinando nada tão aprofundado assim.

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei uma solução simples para este problema.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char nome[10][100];

int i, tam;

int main(){
    printf("\nTamanho: ");
    scanf("%d",&tam);

    for (i=0; i<tam; i++){
        printf("\nEntrada: ");
        getchar();
        scanf("%[^\n]", nome[i]);
        
    }

    for (i=0; i<tam;i++){
        printf("\n%s",nome[i]);
    }
}
```

Usando o getchar para que ele não pule a linha e o ["%[^\n]" no scanf para que ele leia os espaços corretamente, consegui solucionar o problema.
Funciona até para escrever dentro em arquivos também.

Aqui está uma visualização do terminal:

[image: Visualização da Saída]